# Can I build RubyMotion apps with Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, interface-builder, rubymotion

[Ruby Motion](http://www.rubymotion.com) just came out, and the screencast doesn't seem to say anything about whether or not you can use Interface Builder to build your interfaces and integrate them in your RubyMotion project. Is such a thing possible? Or do I really have code everything by hand, not to mention maintain to different pieces of code for iPhone/iPad?

My rep isn't high enough to create a rubymotion tag, so please help out if appropriate.

Comment: try this http://ianp.org/2012/05/07/rubymotion-and-interface-builder/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I'd just like to point out that RubyMotion 1.3 now support automatic compilation of `.xib` files that you put into the `resources` folder. So now the workflow becomes :

1. Create your `.xib` file using XCode (no need to create a project, just use File|New...|File) and save it into the `resources` folder. As there is no support for outlets yet, be careful to set the `tag` property for each control you want to use in your code (you'll find in the property sheet of each component under the "View" header).
2. RubyMotion will take care of compiling your `.xib` file into a `.nib` file, so enjoy :)
3. In your `UIViewController` derived class, load the nib using `loadNibNamed:owner:options:`, as shown below.
4. In `viewDidLoad`, fetch your various components using `viewWithTag:` and add events handlers using `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`,as show below.
5. As a bonus, next time you want to edit your xib, just do `open resources/MyView.xib`, it will only launch the good parts of XCode.

   ```
   class CalculatorViewController < UIViewController
       def loadView
           views = NSBundle.mainBundle.loadNibNamed "Keyboard", owner:self, options:nil
           self.view = views[0]
       end

       def viewDidLoad
           button = view.viewWithTag 1
           button.addTarget self, action:'buttonTapped:', forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside
       end

       def buttonTapped(button)
           # ...
       end
   end
   ```

Comment: Here is a sample project using this technique : [MotionCalc](https://github.com/nlehuen/MotionCalc)

Comment: might want to have a look at this too: http://ianp.org/2012/05/07/rubymotion-and-interface-builder/

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can use Interface Builder in RubyMotion.

.xib files that are located in the resources directory are automatically compiled into .nib files and available to your project.

There is even a way to support outlets if you are so inclined :

> https://github.com/yury/ib#readme
>   http://ianp.org/2012/05/07/rubymotion-and-interface-builder/

Answer (score 1):

But if you really want to use IB then you could still probably use it to lay out your UI and just call

```
NSBundle.mainBundle.loadNibNamed(MY_NIB_NAME, owner:self, options:nil)
```

or similar. I don't think that RubyMotion does any name mangling so you can use your ruby classes in IB by explicitly setting them.

Comment: maybe you could say a little more about how you'd compile an XIB into an NIB for use in a RubyMotion project? that seems to be the tricky part...

Comment: You can just use `ibtool`. The tricky part is connecting up the outlets and actions as you can't use the drag-and-drop features of XCode.

Comment: I tried doing that, passing the options `--compile` and `--flatten NO`, but it keeps throwing an `NSInternalInconsistencyException` at me. I was loading it with `myViewController.alloc.initWithNibName("MyViewController", bundle:nil)`



How exactly do you run `ibtool` to get a loadable nib file?

Answer (score 1):

You can probably build the interface in IB and call the command-line tools to compile the XIB to a NIB.

However, you aren't going to be able to connect outlets or assign actions because IB can't parse the Ruby source files for the `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` tokens. Normally, the NIB loading code makes those connections for you after loading your NIB. You'll have to do that yourself, in code.

Of the two glaring weaknesses in RubyMotion, to me this is the worst. (The other is that lack of code completion will make writing to the Cocoa APIs really tedious.)

Comment: The next version of the ruby mine IDE supports ruby motion development and auto completion of Cocoa APIs. So this might help you

Answer (score 1):

Cappuccino had the same problem. They developed a tool called XcodeCapp: https://github.com/cappuccino/cappuccino/tree/master/Tools/XcodeCapp

It creates "dummy" Obj-C files that you can connect your outlets and actions to in IB, automatically parses them in the background and enables you to use IB to layout your Cappuccino UIs.

It should be possible to take a similar approach with RubyMotion (if you really want to use IB).

- Johannes

Answer (score 0):

There is someone who has made that:

Here is a tutorial video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOapNvehbg4

And this is the website https://github.com/yury/ib

Extra-Tipp: To find wrappers for rubymotion check this source

http://rubymotion-wrappers.com/

Hope this helps